# Viewing of web page from local host and using IP address

Tags: html, internet-explorer, webserver, weblogic

Hi all i have an application using **Oracle WebLogic Server 11gR1 PatchSet 2 at localhost [base_domain]**.I have a problem with this in IE browser if i acess the url using localhost it is displaying fine but if i acess url using IP adress it is having a problem the elements in the page are changing their original positions why is it so?

In Mozilla firefox if i acess the url using localhost or IPaddress everything is working fine.The problem is only with IE when acessing using IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE 8 Microsoft introduced different rendering modes for local and Internet servers so that web developers would break down in tears. By accessing via a different IP address you are causing the server to be treated as being in a different zone.

> If there’s no X-UA-Compatible value and site is in
>   Local Intranet security zone, it will be rendered 
>   in EmulateIE7 mode by default.

Add X-UA-Compatible header or META to force full IE8 (or newer) standards mode.

See also http://sharovatov.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/ie8-rendering-modes-theory-and-practice/